# How to pad an integer number with leading zeros?

Tags: c#

I have strings that are being converted that need to be four characters
long. The values are coming in as anywhere between 0 and 4 characters long.
I need to pad the strings with zeros to make all IDs 4 characters long:

Example

Input number Need

```
1  => 0001
121 => 0121
0567 => 0567
```

So far I have tried:

```
int temCode = 0; 
DataTable dt = objSites.Get_Max_SiteCode();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{ 
     string siteCode = dt.Rows[0]["SiteCode"].ToString();
     string code = siteCode.Substring(siteCode.Length - 4);
     temCode = Convert.ToInt32(code) + 1;
     temCode.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'); // same number is coming here without any pad left.
}
```

Comment: it seems you're doing string manipulations on data, which probably means you're doing a lot of them. I should point out that since strings are immutable, every time you change on it gets thrown out and  new string object created, which is wasteful if you're changing the same string a lot. You may wish to consider [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As has already been said, toString() etc is an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the following:

- `.ToString()`
- `.PadLeft(...)`

all *return* a *new* string, they don't in any way modify the object you call the method on.

Please note that you *have* to place the result into a string. An integer value does not have any concept of padding, so the integer value 0010 is identical to the integer value 10.

So try this:

```
string value = temCode.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
```

or you can use this:

```
string value = temCode.ToString("d4");
```

or this:

```
string value = string.Format("{0:0000}", temCode);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not *doing* anything with the result of `PadLeft` - but you don't need to do that anyway. You can just specify the number of digits (and format) in the `ToString` call:

```
string result = temCode.ToString("d4");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format you number to the length of your choice. Say `code.ToSting("0000")`

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       int i =30;
       String strI = i.ToString("0000");
       Console.WriteLine(strI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use string.padleft.

eg:

```
int i = 100;
int length = 4;

string intString = i.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to integer values 000001 = 1. So you won't be able to your integer with leading zeros as an numeric value. It will need to be stored as a string. So...

```
var foo = 1;
var formatted = foo.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```