# Leading zeros in sum operation using c#.net

Tags: c#

Example :

```
int a = 0000000;
int b = 17;

int c = a + b;
```

c value should be `0000017`

if b `223` means c should be `0000223`

Comment: Note that your declaration of `a` is *exactly* equivalent to `int a = 0;`. The value is just an integer - it doesn't have any notion of leading 0s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673499/how-to-pad-an-integer-number-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 2):

You use for the output using `.ToString("D7")`, read more in this article [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
c.ToString("D7");
```

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeroes has sense in a string. You get it as following:

```
result.ToString("D7")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `0` and `0000000` are the *same* integer numbers; if you want different `String` representation, then use *formatting*:

```
  int a = 0000000; // equals to 0
  int b = 17;

  int c = a + b;

  Console.Write(c.ToString("D7"));  // 7 digits, "0000000" format will do the same
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this method:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
    int a = 0000000;
    int b = 17;
    String s = String.Format("{0,10:0000000}",a+b);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
   }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0000017
```

Comment: Question is about C#, this is C++.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the post. Try out and see. For more info on string formatting refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In application, leading zeroes only have sense when they are displayed which means when they are actually `strings`.
In numeric form you don't see and by that do/should not care.

So, don't care about leading zeroes in `int` variables. When you want to show them or otherwise use in `string` use `c.ToString("D7")`. Of course, you can change to any number of digits, 7 is only for your example.